# Allow docker containers on the bridge network to connect to the host using iptables

Tags: iptables, docker, haproxy

I have recently tried deploying iptables to only expose relevant ports.
I'm dropping every incoming connection using
`iptables -P INPUT DROP`
and later on allowing access to relevant ports.
This does work but breaks my haproxy setup with web servers running in docker containers. The containers now can't connect to the host network.
I tried allowing the docker containers to connect to the host using

```
Iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -j Accept
```

But this doesn't work and the web servers are still unable to respond to haproxy.
I'd appreciate any idea on how to fix this and allow the containers to connect to the host again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about web servers or HAProxy, but I can give you some IPtables advice and then answer your question.

1. IPtables reads the rules top-down and stops reading the rules when it reaches a DROP, REJECT, or ACCEPT.
2. IPtables is case-sensitive. `Accept` is not the same as `ACCEPT`
3. IPtables policy `-P` is used when no other rule in the table applies to a given packet.
4. Make sure when you are adding new IPtables rules, you are flushing the old ones out by entering `iptables -t filter -F` and then `iptables -t filter -X`. These two commands will flush the filter table (default table) and also clear out any subchains in the table.
5. Make sure rules on the clients are reflected on the host and make sure rules on the host are reflected on the clients.

To answer your question...

First, try completely flushing your firewall by running these commands to flush all of the tables in IPtables:

```
iptables -t raw -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t raw -X
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t filter -X
```

Then make sure no other firewall is running.

CentOS/Fedora/Rhel:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
systemctl stop ufw
```

Then, do some testing. Does HAProxy work? If it does work, your problem is the firewall. If it does *not* work, then you need to revise your IPtables rules. Maybe start by making your IPtables rules as non-specific as possible and then become more and more specific. Here are my recommendations to start off on:

Make sure loopback traffic is enabled on the server. Loopback traffic never leaves the server:

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Try whitelisting the IP of the HAProxy server instead of the port:

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -s ${HAPROXY_IP} -j ACCEPT
```

Allow `ESTABLISHED` and `RELATED` connections:

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: To flush rules, policy must be set to accept first (`-P ACCEPT`) , or connectivity loss will follow.